# Padding bottom is not working in generated document

Tags: javascript, css, tinymce, docx

I manage final viva sheets in a university and I want to provide a total
client side / vanilla JS solution to faculty to generate final viva sheets.

Things went well with TinyMCE, but in one of HTML table cells in the generated docx file, I need it to set to bottom aligned, but it always has some space/margin/padding that I can
remove manually but not in the code. I have tried playing with CSS margin, padding, line height etc. but all in vain. Only due to this issue my further work is stopped. Here is JS Fiddle Link, please check

```
if(x===7) { c.style.verticalAlign="bottom"; c.style.fontSize="8pt"; 
    c.style.paddingBottom="0";    
    c.style.margin="0 0 0 0";
    }
```

[JS Fiddle Link](https://jsfiddle.net/usman400/y5fumdo8/4/)

The thing looks fine in the editor but not in the downloaded file
(click on Convert button to download file)

The issue is with the text: "Teacher Two Name" in the generated document.
as it always has some padding or space under it

inside the code, it is at line 145, please help

Here is what I am getting
[image]

And here is what I need
[image]

Comment: Please check the fiddle and help

Comment: There is no space under Teacher Two Name table cell. It's placed at the bottom

Comment: its in the downloaded file, plz click on Convert button

Comment: I clicked on convert and opened generated file. And there is still no space at the bottom of that cell.

Comment: I updated the OP with images, plz check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved with help of a colleague, the trick is to add the text "Teacher Two Name" in my JS array as: `"<p style='display:inline; margin:0px'>Teacher Two Name</p>"` and it works well now

It even resolved another issue that I compromised earlier being little issue i.e.
In my JS code, I was unable to apply exactly 12pt font size in the generated docx file for last row of the table (whatever number i put it either goes 12.5 or 13 but not exactly 12pt, so I used the same solution to apply font size inline and it resolved that too:

```
<p style='font-size: 12pt;'>SomeStudentID (Some Info) 9:55 AM</p>
```

Thanks for all valuable help though

Answer (score 1):

[image: Reference]

I don't see any padding below it. Check your screen resolution. I'm using 1920 x 1080

Comment: Thats the problem sir, in the editor there is no padding, but click on Convert button, it will download a Word file, that file contains the padding I am talking about, sorry as I didnt indicated it in OP, I have updated it now

Comment: I have clicked on the Convert button and it downloaded the file. I see 'Teacher Two Name' text centered vertically & horizontally in the cell. It's looking perfect.
You don't want to vertically center it in the cell?

Comment: I actually get a space under "Teacher Two Name" which is shown as Paragraph spacing inside MS Word, that I can remove manually